# Pandas DataFrame: Replace all values that have a comma with a dot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

> I have a latitude column written with commas and dots. And I want to
> convert this column to float but there are some cells written with
> commas making this not possible, so I have to replace the commas with
> the points. But when I trying this function below it was not possible
> to replace with points. I believe that this function only replaces if
> all values have commas but there are only some that have commas and
> so it doesn't do the replacement.

```
df["LAT"].replace(",",".")
```

> Here is the dataframe:

```
     ID      LAT      LNG  
0   PLU  -12.453  -32.623 
1   OJE  -13,789  -31.933  
2   RFA  -10.157  -31.821
3   TYE  -11.253  -32.081 
4   VOL  -12,792  -32.487
```

> Expected output:

```
     ID      LAT      LNG  
0   PLU  -12.453  -32.623 
1   OJE  -13.789  -31.933  
2   RFA  -10.157  -31.821
3   TYE  -11.253  -32.081 
4   VOL  -12.792  -32.487
```

> So I can finally convert the column to a float:

```
df["LAT"].astype(float)
```

> Does someone know how do I replace these commas?

Comment: `df['LAT'].str.replace(",",".").astype(float)` ?

Comment: You just need the `.str` part: `df["LAT"].str.replace(",", ".")`

Comment: If I do this, all the other cells that already have the dot become NaN.

Comment: Convert the entire column to str  first:  `df['LAT'].astype(str).str.replace(",", ".").astype(float)`

Comment: @Psidom, thnks man! You're life saver. It worked out!

Answer (score 0):

Are you assigning the result of the replace function back to the column you want to change?

Like:

```
data["LAT"] = data["LAT"].str.replace(',', '.')
```

or

```
data["LAT"].str.replace(',', '.', inplace=True)
```

If you are doing so, and still does not work. Try with these 3 alternatives:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',', '.'))

pd.read_csv('/your_path/your_file.csv', sep=';', decimal='.')

df.stack().str.replace(',', '.').unstack()
```

Comment: Thanks man but your solution is incomplete. df['LAT'].astype(str).str.replace(",", ".").astype(float) solve my problem.

Comment: data["LAT"].str.replace(',', '.', inplace=True) , this will cause an error
(TypeError: replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inplace')